# Как сделать, чтобы событие было только для одной кнопки?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Из БД берутся данные, которые потом преобразуются в карточки.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При нажатии на кнопку открывается вторая форма карточки.
Проблема в том, что кнопка срабатывает для всех карточек, а не для одной.

Html

```
{% if tasks %}
<div class="row">
{% for el in tasks %}
    <div class="cards col-sm-6">
        <div class="cards_1 card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Какой-то текст</h5>
                <p class="card-text">{{ el.title }}</p>
                <button class="btn_1 btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="close">Смотреть перевод</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="cards_2 card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Какой-то текст</h5>
                <p class="card-text">{{ el.task}}</p>
                <button class="btn_2 btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="close">Вернуться</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

JS

```
const content = document.querySelectorAll(".cards_1");
const contents = document.querySelectorAll(".cards_2");
let bShow = document.querySelectorAll('.btn_1');
let bShow_2 = document.querySelectorAll('.btn_2');
$('.cards_2').hide();

for (let i = 0; i < bShow.length; i++) {
  bShow[i].onclick = function() {
    $('.cards_1').hide();
    $('.cards_2').show();
    console.log("2")
  }
  bShow_2[i].onclick = function(){
    $('.cards_1').show();
    $('.cards_2').hide();
  }
}
```

Comment: Зачем эта смесь JS и JQ?

Answer (score 0):

```js
const cards = document.querySelectorAll('.cards');

cards.forEach(card =>
{
  card.addEventListener('click', ({target}) =>
  {
    const card1   = card.querySelector('.cards_1');
    const card2   = card.querySelector('.cards_2');
    
    if (target.classList.contains('btn_1'))
    {
      card1.classList.add('card--hide');
      card2.classList.remove('card--hide');
    }
    else if (target.classList.contains('btn_2'))
    {
      card1.classList.remove('card--hide');
      card2.classList.add('card--hide');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.cards
{
  border: 1px solid #000;
  
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.card--hide
{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="cards col-sm-6">
        <div class="cards_1 card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Какой-то текст</h5>
                <p class="card-text">{{ el.title }}</p>
                <button class="btn_1 btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="close">Смотреть перевод</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="cards_2 card card--hide">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Какой-то текст</h5>
                <p class="card-text">{{ el.task}}</p>
                <button class="btn_2 btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="close">Вернуться</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="cards col-sm-6">
        <div class="cards_1 card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Какой-то текст</h5>
                <p class="card-text">{{ el.title }}</p>
                <button class="btn_1 btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="close">Смотреть перевод</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="cards_2 card card--hide">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Какой-то текст</h5>
                <p class="card-text">{{ el.task}}</p>
                <button class="btn_2 btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="close">Вернуться</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="cards col-sm-6">
        <div class="cards_1 card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Какой-то текст</h5>
                <p class="card-text">{{ el.title }}</p>
                <button class="btn_1 btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="close">Смотреть перевод</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="cards_2 card card--hide">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Какой-то текст</h5>
                <p class="card-text">{{ el.task}}</p>
                <button class="btn_2 btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="close">Вернуться</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Странно, но теперь элементы вовсе удаляются

Answer (score 0):

Потому что у вас вот тут

```
$('.cards_1').hide()
$('.cards_2').show()
```

действие происходит сразу для всех `cards_1 и cards_2`. А вам надо отталкиваться от элемента, на который нажали и искать его родителя с классом `cards_1 и cards_2` и показывать/скрывать его